# Get grouped product by associated

Tags: product, grouped-products

I need to detect if product is associated product of grouped product and if it is get this grouped product. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You mean, if the product is associated with any grouped product then get the parent grouped product? Or do you want to know if the current product is a grouped product then get all of its associated products

Comment: @TBIInfotech, first. if the product is associated with any grouped product then get the parent grouped product

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have the product in question `$product`.
Try this:

```
$groupedParentsIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')
                   ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
```

Now that you have the parent ids you can easily get the product instances using

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);
```

or

```
$parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$groupedParentsIds))
```

Comment: works perfect!!

Answer (score 2):

Get Current product Id
 say `$id`

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$productType=$product->getTypeID();
if($productType == "simple"){
    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($id); // check for grouped product
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use product_id to get the group parents ids

> $_grouped_parents_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')
>                ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());

2. Iterate the $_grouped_parents_id to reload the group product by the id.

```
foreach($_grouped_parents_id as $_product_id) {
           $group_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product_id);  
        $associated_products = $group_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($group_product);
 }
```

Comment: I have checked it but not got all associated, can you please verify it again, and share the output.

Comment: I added the code how to get the associated products by group product id. The output of $_grouped_parents_id is an array.